# How do you fix the apps aren't loaded yet error in Django using django-mysql?

Tags: python, django, django-mysql

Im getting this error when trying to start Django in pycharm. I don't understand as it was running properly yesterday.

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Here is the full trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthew/PycharmProjects/GluIQ/DreamIt/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Home.models import QuestionAwner, userProject, Files
  File "/Users/matthew/PycharmProjects/GluIQ/Home/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django_mysql.models import JSONField
  File "/Users/matthew/python3venv/gluiq/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_mysql/models/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django_mysql.models.base import Model  # noqa
  File "/Users/matthew/python3venv/gluiq/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_mysql/models/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Model(models.Model):
  File "/Users/matthew/python3venv/gluiq/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/matthew/python3venv/gluiq/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/matthew/python3venv/gluiq/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Here are the imports for views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from Home.models import QuestionAwner, userProject, Files
from django.views.generic import View
from DreamIt.forms import ProjectMandateForm, StatementOfNeedForm
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
```

Here are the imports for models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django_mysql.models import JSONField
```

Here are my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'DreamIt.apps.DreamitConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_mysql',
]
```

Heres are what I have installed:

```
django==1.11.20
PyMySQL==0.9.3
coverage==4.5.2
django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker==2.2.3
django-braces==1.13.0
django-mysql==2.4.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.15
pip==10.0.1
protobuf==3.6.1
pytz==2018.9
setuptools==39.1.0
six==1.12.0
```

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. I'm sure I've done something stupid yesterday and forgotten.

Comment: What happens if you move your apps below the Django apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Exactly the same error

Comment: I worked it out, but i'm kind of worried it took me so long. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was me being an idiot, i had not selected for PyCharm to run my app using Django.

For anyone who does this as well its the dropdown in the top right of PyCharm.